# How can I update another Model using a Callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I'm working with a Model called Recover. Prior to creating the model I would like to save the boolean attribute, Combo.occupied = true using the Recover.combo_id attribute as a reference.

It appears my SQL is executing the query properly, but it is not saving this attribute. How can I save Combo.occupied = true?

recover.rb:

> before_create :checkin
>
> protected
>
> def checkin
>         x = Combo.find_by_id(combo_id).occupied =
>   true
>   end

Rails Console:

> Started POST "/recovers" for 127.0.0.1
>   at 2011-01-06 17:07:24 -0800
>   Processing by
>   RecoversController#create as HTML
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"o1Iu3Y9/rVBOZPoDUgVP/tRfQ8GxbdWC40DbPq9YxUE=",
>   "recover"=>{"combo_id"=>"4",
>   "email"=>"jz@marin.edu"},
>   "commit"=>"Create Recover"}   Recover
>   Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "recovers"."id"
>   FROM "recovers" WHERE
>   ("recovers"."email" =
>   'justin.zollars@marin.edu') LIMIT 1
>   Recover Load (0.1ms)  SELECT
>   "recovers"."id" FROM "recovers" WHERE
>   ("recovers"."combo_id" = 4) LIMIT 1
>   Combo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "combos".*
>   FROM "combos" WHERE ("combos"."id" =
>   4) LIMIT 1   AREL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO
>   "recovers" ("locker_number", "email",
>   "requests", "created_at",
>   "updated_at", "combo_id") VALUES
>   (NULL, 'justin.zollars@marin.edu',
>   NULL, '2011-01-07 01:07:24.287072',
>   '2011-01-07 01:07:24.287072', 4)
>   Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/recovers/14
>   Completed 302 Found in 119ms

RecoversController#create

> def create
>       @recover = Recover.new(params[:recover])
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @recover.save
>     format.html { redirect_to(@recover, :notice =>
> ```
>
> 'Recover was successfully created.') }
>           format.xml  { render :xml => @recover, :status => :created,
>
> :location => @recover }
>
> ```
>   else
>     format.html { render :action => "new" }
>     format.xml  { render :xml => @recover.errors, :status =>
> ```
>
> :unprocessable_entity }
>         end
>
> ```
> end
> ```
>
> end

Comment: it's seems no object is created in your RecoversController#create. Could you post the content of this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call save for the new value to be written to the database:

```
def checkin
  combo = Combo.find_by_id(combo_id)
  combo.occupied = true
  combo.save!
end
```

This is easier if you use `update_attribute`. Also, if you have a belongs_to relationship, you can dispense with the `find`:

```
belongs_to :combo

def checkin
  if combo # true unless combo_id is nil
    combo.update_attribute(:occupied,true)
  end
end
```

Note that `update_attribute` bypasses validation. If you need to validate, use `update_attributes(:occupied=>true)` instead.

Comment: damn too late for me but +1 ;)